# Css, внешнее отступы между строчками(не ячейками) таблицы

Tags: css

Здравствуйте,

Как можно добавить внешнее отступы между строчками(не ячейками) таблицы? 
Что бы было чтото типа:

<table>
<tr><td>Ячейка</td></tr>
Отступ
<tr><td>Ячейка</td></tr>
</table>

Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Просто применяем padding-bottom ко всем ячейкам, за исключением последней строки:

```
tr:not(:last-of-type) td {
    padding-bottom: 20px;
}
```

[http://jsfiddle.net/8u6UU](http://jsfiddle.net/8u6UU/)